# finding the running time for my algorithm for finding whether an input is prime in terms of the input

Tags: c++, big-o, primes

This is my function for finding prime numbers

```
void print(int num)
{
    for(int i=2; i<num/2; i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            cout<<"not prime\n";
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    cout<<"prime\n";        
}
```

My input in num. I'm trying to find the runtime using big oh. I remember that finding the run time had something to do with log.

The worst case would be that my program would run the n/2 -1 times?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but this code is very inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the loop runs n/2-1 times and only contains commands of constant complexity, so your runtime scales as a*(n/2-1) for some a. In big-o this is written as O(n/2-1) and because constant factors don't matter this is equal to O(n).

(as an aside: it is actually theta(n) which means, that it is not just bounded from above by n but also from below by n)

Comment: @TonyD too bad I mixed up little o and theta :-( it is actually theta(n) and not o(n). I will change it to O(n) because it is much better known than theta...